# Why is my python PyPDF2 'reader' object being inadvertently converted to a string?

Tags: python, object, python-docx, pypdf

long time reader, first time poster. My question involves an issue I’m having with a script I’ve been writing for personal use to develop my own python toolkit and just as general practice. It uses PyPDF2, python-docx and tkinter modules. The issue I’m having is kind of complicated, but I’ll try to summarize as best as I can.

To start off, the purpose of this program is to pull user defined pages from a PDF file, such as pulling the glossary from a PDF textbook for annotation purposes and saving them in docx format.

I have created functions to allow the user to choose to copy a single or multiple pages, name the file containing these pages, and select the directory the file is then saved in. I have also included a function that allows the user to back up through the process in the case that they make a mistake. My problem is that if the user chooses to back up after a page number is given to copy a single page, the pdf 'reader' object is somehow converted from an object to a string. This means that when the user is again prompted to enter a page number to copy, the 'reader' variable no longer points to the location of the document object and instead takes on the form of the actual contents of the page itself, which is obviously not what I want. So far, I have been unable to identify the cause of this.

The file is rather large to be included here, so ill provide a GitHub link for those who wish to view and/or test the script.

I’m hoping someone here can provide some insight as to why this might be. Thanks so much.

https://github.com/ClntK/ClintsPDFtoDOCX/blob/main/PdfFileReader3.py

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ima3u.png)

Comment: Look at the call in line 260.

Comment: ah.. i think im starting to pick up what youre putting down.. its calling the saveAsDocx function... maybe if i create another parameter in the saveAsDocx function to provide the function i wish to call as an argument instead of always directing it to recall the saveAsDocx function?? thanks for the lead. i appreciate your input.

Comment: Well it is just that the call of "back" in line 260 has a wrong argument.

Comment: oh.. i was looking at the wrong line. hmm. ive tried to replace the 'one' argument on line 260 with an argument that passes the name of the function that was chosen by the user(either the 'one' function or the 'firstPageFunc' function), but im still getting the same results. looks like i havent found the issue yet.

Comment: GitHub file has been updated.

Comment: In the original code "back" calls "one" and gives it some arguments. Look at these arguments and see how they match the parameters of the "one" function. There is something that doesn't match.

Comment: oh man.. found it. i got lost in my own code. i was using output as an argument in place of what should have been the reader object.. should've been obvious. thanks so much for the help, its working perfectly now. id also be happy to accept any other advice or input you may have. regardless i appreciate your time.